# Realm in Xamarin Forms: Another "rhs of the binary operator 'Equal' should be a constant or closure variable expression" issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq, realm

I want to cast a realm collection to a list, then project it. However, doing this immediately triggers an error. The error I'm receiving is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437550/realm-dotnet-the-rhs-of-the-binary-operator-equal-should-be-a-constant-or-cl) problem, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763893/how-to-check-for-null-on-nullable-types-using-linq-expression-in-realm), but seems to be happening for a different (unknown) reason, since it appears the answers in those two questions don't apply to my condition (I'm using a newer version of Realm and I am not using a property accessor call in the predicate lambda).

I'm using my realm collection to project into a different type. I know that the current version of Realm (0.81.0) doesn't support `.Select()` so I am calling `.ToList()` and then projecting. The stack trace shows that the origin of the exception is the `.ToList()` call.

My Code:

```
private void BuildAndApplyBindingContext(int listId)
{
    realm.All<MemberInventoryItem>()
        .Where(i => i.InventoryListId == listId)
        .ToList()
        .Select(i => new ItemListEntryViewModel {
            Id = i.InventoryItemId,
            Type = i.IsAcquired ? InventoryType.Item : InventoryType.UnacquiredListItem,
            Name = i.Item,
            IsAcquired = i.IsAcquired,
            SubText = UiHelper.GetLocationString(i),
            BadgeText = UiHelper.GetBadgeText(i),
            ImageRef = UiHelper.SetMissingImage(i.ImageUrl),
            ExpiresDate = i.ExpiresDate,
            ShowNoticeText = i.ExpiresDate < DateTime.Now
            }).OrderBy(i => i.Name)
        .ToList()
    };

    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The rhs of the binary operator 'Equal' should be a constant or closure variable expression. 
Unable to process `Convert(value(Prepify.App.Pages.Inventory.ListDetail.DetailTab+<>c__DisplayClass7_0).listId)`
```

Something to note, and I have no idea if it matters or not, but the property `InventoryListId` in my `.Where()` clause is of type `int?`. Should this matter?

Using Realm Xamarin v0.81.0 on Forms/Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Something to note, and I have no idea if it matters or not, but the property `InventoryListId` in my `.Where()` clause is of type `int?`. Should this matter?

Good that you thought to include that in your question. It would make sense that it matters. It means your

> ```
> .Where(i => i.InventoryListId == listId)
> ```

is actually

```
.Where(i => i.InventoryListId == (int?)listId)
```

and this conversion is present in the generated expression tree. That's why you're seeing `Convert(...)` in the exception message.

Your LINQ provider's exception message says it requires either a constant or a closure variable expression, and a converted closure variable expression is neither.

And that's avoidable the same way as in the question you link to: explicitly store it in a local variable instead.

```
private void BuildAndApplyBindingContext(int listId)
{
    int? listIdNullable = listId;
    realm.All<MemberInventoryItem>()
        .Where(i => i.InventoryListId == listIdNullable)
        ...
```

Comment: I will give this a go later today. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, it worked great

Comment: why no love for my question? :)